# What PDF readers support lean back reading for Android box?

Tags: pdf-viewer, bookmark, android-tv, remote-control

Most remote controls of Android boxes like MiBOX 3c only support Dpad, not mouse. Unfortunately, this means that a simple PDF reader does not necessary work with remote control, since it can't mimic a finger tap on screen like in phones. To be able to lean on sofa and still learning, I'm looking for a PDF reader that satisfies these requirements:

- Selecting files
- Scrolling pages
- Navigating to the outline (aka bookmark, aka table of content)

Below is my review.

---

## Mouse-required for outline

- [Aldiko Book Reader](https://aldiko-book-reader.en.uptodown.com/android) & [Foxit PDF](https://foxit-pdf.en.uptodown.com/android): nice graphic, but cannot even scroll by remote
- [PDF Reader](https://kdan-mobile-software-ltd-pdf-reader.en.uptodown.com/android) by Kdan: support cloud (38 MB)
- [Adobe Reader](https://adobe-reader.en.uptodown.com/android): nice graphic and fast (50 MB)

## Remote-control-friendly but doesn't support outline

- [FB Reader](https://fbreader.en.uptodown.com/android/download): slow rendering, customized buttons (44 MB, including the PDF plugin).
- [APV Reader](https://apv-pdf-viewer.en.uptodown.com/android): very lightweight (7 MB)
- [PDF Reader](https://pdf-reader.en.uptodown.com/android), [Ebook and PDF Reader](https://ebook-and-pdf-reader.en.uptodown.com/android): these two apps are the same, and actually in theory they can show outline, but for unknown reason they can't. Menu can be shown with the middle button. Fast searching and smooth rendering, but the "go to page" screen doesn't support remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Moon Reader](https://moon-reader.en.uptodown.com/android)

The author really knows what users need even when the app is written for regular phone users. The functions that can be assigned for buttons are extremely useful. I highly recommend it.